# Protect category assignment in MediaWiki

Tags: php, permissions, categories, mediawiki, wiki

Is it possible to protect specific category so that e.g. the category 'category1' cannot be assigned to an article without certain permission?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could check if the category was added to the page in the [`ArticleSave`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/ArticleSave) hook and issue an error if the user doesn't have the required permission.

**Edit:** Something along these lines (quick & dirty):

```
$wgForbiddenCats = array( 'Forbidden' => 'sysop' );

$wgHooks['ArticleSave'][] = 'checkForbiddenCats';
function checkForbiddenCats( $article, $user, $text, $summary, $minor,
    $_, $_, $flags, $status )
{
    global $wgForbiddenCats, $wgParser;

    // Firstly, get categories in the new text
    $parser_output = $wgParser->parse( $text, $article->getTitle(),
        $article->getParserOptions() );
    $new_cats = array_keys( $parser_output->getCategories() );

    // For now, the only added categories are the ones in the submitted text
    $added_cats = $new_cats;

    // If the page already exists, it can have some categories already
    if( !( $flags & EDIT_NEW ) ) {
        $dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );
        $query_result = $dbr->select(
            'categorylinks',
            'cl_to',
            array( 'cl_from' => $article->getID() ) );

        $old_cats = array();
        while( $row = $query_result->fetchRow() )
            $old_cats[] = $row[0];
        $dbr->freeResult( $query_result );

        $added_cats = array_diff( $new_cats, $old_cats );
    }

    $user_groups = $user->getGroups();
    foreach( $wgForbiddenCats as $category => $group ) {
        if( array_search( $category, $added_cats ) !== false &&
            array_search( $group, $user_groups ) === false )
        {
            $status->fatal( 'forbidden-cat' );
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little over the top for what you want but I think you can use [SimpleSecurity](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSimpleSecurity) for this, but it might also ensure people without permission cannot *view* the category either.

Comment: SimpleSecurity would allow you to make it so only certain people can edit certain categories, but I don't think this is what they want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what I want to do is restrict adding specific category to an article.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely, since adding a category is as simple as adding some text, this isn't an action that can be restricted with the default installation, or an extension I could find.

I guess one could write and extension that would remove the text if you don't have permission to add that category.